# Getting the max value of a two dimentional array with Laravel collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, max, laravel-8

I'm trying to get the max value of a two-dimensional array with Laravel using collections but the result that I get I really weird.

My code :

```php
dump($this->data);
dump(collect($this->data)->max());
dd(max(collect($this->data)->max()));
```

The result :

```php
array:8 [▼
  "2021-03-15" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 0
    "free_time" => 0
  ]
  "2021-03-16" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 740.2
    "free_time" => 316.62
  ]
  "2021-03-17" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 623.46
    "free_time" => 1953.46
  ]
  "2021-03-18" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 1445.85
    "free_time" => 512.29
  ]
  "2021-03-19" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 477.76
    "free_time" => 545.28
  ]
  "2021-03-20" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 414.61
    "free_time" => 923.5
  ]
  "2021-03-21" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 803.16
    "free_time" => 115.34
  ]
  "2021-03-22" => array:2 [▼
    "premium_time" => 401.14
    "free_time" => 802.73
  ]
]

array:2 [▼
  "premium_time" => 1445.85
  "free_time" => 512.29
]

1445.85
```

The correct maximum is `1943.56` and not `1445.85`. This result makes no sense for me.

However, `max()` works when I specify a key, but in this case I have to loop all arrays... For example, this function works :

```php
private function get_max(array $charts, array $data){
    $max = 0;
    foreach($charts as $k => $v){
        $local_max = collect($this->data)->max($k);

        if($local_max > $max){
            $max = $local_max;
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

So my questions are :

1. Do you know what `max()` really do?
2. Do you know if my `foreach` solution is the better one?

Cheers

Comment: Try using [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten) and then [max](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-max) `collect($this->data)->flatten()->max();`

Comment: I can't believe I missed the `flatten()` method. It indeed works !

I have however no Idea how to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten) and then [max](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-max).

```
collect($this->data)->flatten()->max();
```

You can read in the documentation, through the links provided, what each of these methods does.

Example of the result of each one:

```
$array = [
    "2021-03-15" => [
        "premium_time" => 0,
        "free_time" => 0
    ],
    "2021-03-16" => [
        "premium_time" => 740.2,
        "free_time" => 316.62
    ],
    "2021-03-17" => [
        "premium_time" => 623.46,
        "free_time" => 1953.46
    ],
    "2021-03-18" => [
        "premium_time" => 1445.85,
        "free_time" => 512.29
    ],
    "2021-03-19" => [
        "premium_time" => 477.76,
        "free_time" => 545.28
    ],
    "2021-03-20" => [
        "premium_time" => 414.61,
        "free_time" => 923.5
    ],
    "2021-03-21" => [
        "premium_time" => 803.16,
        "free_time" => 115.34
    ],
    "2021-03-22" => [
        "premium_time" => 401.14,
        "free_time" => 802.73
    ]
];

dump(collect($array)->flatten());
/*
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1863 ▼
  #items: array:16 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
    2 => 740.2
    3 => 316.62
    4 => 623.46
    5 => 1953.46
    6 => 1445.85
    7 => 512.29
    8 => 477.76
    9 => 545.28
    10 => 414.61
    11 => 923.5
    12 => 803.16
    13 => 115.34
    14 => 401.14
    15 => 802.73
  ]
}
*/

dump(collect($array)->flatten()->max());
// 1953.46
```